# Django safe filter breaks jinja template

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

```html
<p class="card-text">
    {{ blog_post.description_from_content|safe}}
</p>
```

The above comes from the Django/Mezzanine web framework

The above will render an empty p tag, and place the contents outside the p tag. If you remove the safe filter then it renders as expected. (inside the p tag).

Any idea why this is happening? I can't just remove safe as the content contains html
[How it renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CRVk.jpg)